# What fault occurs if a volleyball forearm pass is made without the hands connected?

Tags: rules, volleyball

I'm wondering, what would the call be if a player attempted a forearm pass but didn't have their hands connected? would it be a carry ball, a double hit, a foot fault, or 4 hits?

Answer (score 3):

Making a forearm pass without your hands connected is not *of itself* a fault. Quoting from [the FIVB 2017-2020 official rules, Section 9.3 "Faults in playing the ball"](https://www.fivb.org/en/refereeing-rules/documents/FIVB-Volleyball_Rules_2017-2020-EN-v06.pdf):

> 9.3.3 CATCH: the ball is caught and/or thrown; it does not rebound from the hit.
>
> 9.3.4 DOUBLE CONTACT: a player hits the ball twice in succession or the ball contacts various parts of his/her body in succession.

So long as the ball is not caught and is not a double contact, it is a legal play on the ball - that is all that is required, the form of the contact is (deliberately) not specified in the rules.